# Тэг url не видит аргумент

Tags: django, django-urls

В шаблоне имеется ссылка

```html
<a href="{% url inline_admin_formset.opts.opts|admin_urlname:'labour' inline_admin_form.original.pk|admin_urlquote %}" class="historylink" style="margin-left: 5px;">Трудозатраты</a>
```

Когда рендерится страница с этой ссылкой, я получаю ошибку:

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/roadmaps/roadmap/1/change/

Reverse for 'roadmaps_point_labour' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/roadmaps/roadmap/point/(?P<object_id>.+)/labour/$']
```

С передаваемым аргументом всё нормально, он присутствует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```html
{% url inline_admin_formset.opts.opts|admin_urlname:'labour' inline_admin_form.original.pk|admin_urlquote as labour_inline_url%}

<a href="{{ labour_inline_url }}" class="historylink" style="margin-left: 5px;">Трудозатраты</a>
```